# MassTransit - Configure Retry for Azure Service Bus Message Delivery

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I am trying to send messages to Azure Service Bus Queue. I am expecting for MassTransit to retry delivery if the connection fails.

My message sender utility:

```cs
public class MessageSender : IMessageSender
{
    private readonly IServiceBus _serviceBus;
    
    public MessageSender(IServiceBus serviceBus)
    {
        _serviceBus = serviceBus;
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(IMessage message)
    {
        await _serviceBus.Send(message);
    }
}
```

I set MassTransit configuration in another class, that is injected in the message sender utility.

```cs
public class MassTransitAzureServiceBus : IServiceBus
{
    private IBusControl _busControl;

    public MassTransitAzureServiceBus()
    {
        _busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host(new Uri(serviceBusUri), h => 
                {
                    h.NamedKeyCredential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential("name","key");

                    h.RetryLimit = 8; // this is not being honored
                });
            });
    }
}
```

Then I send message like this:

```cs
public async Task Send<TMessage>(TMessage message) where TMessage : IMessage
{
     var sendEndpoint = await _busControl.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue-uri"));
     await sendEndpoint.Send(message, typeof(TMessage));
}
```

**I intentionally disconnect internet or provide wrong connection string for service bus as a delivery failure test.**

**It retries 4 times then throws an error, disregarding the retry limit set by me.**

`Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (No such host is known. (myhost.servicebus.windows.net:443)) (No such host is known. (myhost.servicebus.windows.net:443)) (No such host is known. (myhost.servicebus.windows.net:443)) (No such host is known. (myhost.servicebus.windows.net:443))`

I have also tried the following, does not work.

```cs
_busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    cfg.UseMessageRetry(x =>
    {
        x.Immediate(2); // this is not being honored either
    });

    cfg.Host(new Uri(serviceBusUri), h => 
    {
        h.NamedKeyCredential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential("name","key");
    });
});
```

Is there a way to retry message delivery without using services like Polly? I have used Polly for retrying before, thought I could get rid of it with using MassTransit built-in retry mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

First, `UseMessageRetry` is for *consuming* messages – it isn't at all related to sending or publishing messages.

Second, [MassTransit will retry](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/d289ae1ce58da7c5477d37558c5b8fce0fb57e5d/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Configuration/ServiceBusHostConfiguration.cs#L35) any of the exception types shown in that retry configuration exponentially up to 1000 times, including publish/send.

Third, you aren't starting the bus. The bus should be created, at startup, and started. When the process shuts down, the bus should be stopped.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, there is no way to configure retry count for message delivery?

What is `h.RetryLimit` used for?

Comment: Those values are [passed directly to the service bus retry options](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/3ade029ad145ff25b42ff90868b79b9b19cc0dd2/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/ConnectionContextFactory.cs#L61), but MassTransit does its own retry on top of the built-in SDK retry.